# Can't open a list of websites in selenium one by one?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As I am trying to automate a simple task of opening a list of websites one by one and close. But the program opens the first website successfully and closes it but it cannot open the next website in the list , The error shows the `NoSuchElementException` but I have double checked the XPath and it still shows the error. Here is the code

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://omayo.blogspot.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List<WebElement> link = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"LinkList1\"]/div/ul/li"));
        int no_of_link=link.size();
        String path="//*[@id=\"LinkList1\"]/div/ul/li";
        for (int i=1;i<=no_of_link;i++){
            String e_path =path+"["+i+"]";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(e_path)).click();
//            driver.wait(10);
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I tried using multiple lists of website to execute the program but it halt at some point and showsNoSuchElementException error. Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="LinkList1"]/div/ul/li[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.70)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [49ead12a686f093d53ab12e5fa475223, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id="LinkList1"]/div/ul/li[3]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 122.0.6261.70, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 122.0.6261.128 (f18a44fedeb..., userDataDir: C:\Users\prabh\AppData\Loca...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54080}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:54080/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 122.0.6261.70, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 49ead12a686f093d53ab12e5fa475223
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
    at demo.main(demo.java:20)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code with in-line explanation:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://omayo.blogspot.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
# Captures all the anchor tags(<a>) into a List
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='LinkList1']/div/ul/li/a"));

# Below loop will iterate through each link. Clicks it, navigates back, repeats until end of loop       
for (WebElement link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
    link.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.navigate().back();
}
driver.quit();
```

Comment: It worked like a charm i think the for loop is the problem. is it ?

Comment: Yes, it was the for loop.